# MySQL Selecting related data in one of multiple possible tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, relational-database

I have 8 tables, Groups, Items and 6 various Type tables. Groups contain multiple items and an item is of a certain type (1-1 relationship between item and type).

Sample data would be as follows:

Group table:

```
----------------------------
| groupID (PK) | groupName |
----------------------------
| 1            | Buying    | 
| 2            | Selling   |
----------------------------
```

Item table:

```
--------------------------------------------
| itemID (PK) | groupID (FK) | itemName    |
--------------------------------------------
| 10          | 1            | Rugby Ball  |
| 11          | 2            | Kettle      |
| 12          | 2            | Soccer Ball |
| 13          | 1            | Toaster     |
| 14          | 1            | Couch       |
--------------------------------------------
```

Type tables:
type1 (Appliances):

```
--------------------------------------------------
| appliancesID (PK) | itemID (FK) | energyRating |
--------------------------------------------------
| 20                | 11          | 5            |
| 21                | 13          | 3            |
--------------------------------------------------
```

type2 (Balls):

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| ballID (PK) | itemID (FK) | inflateTo | Size         |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 33          | 10          | 20 psi    | Junior       |
| 34          | 12          | 40 psi    | Professional |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to execute a query that returns a group including all of it's items and their related type information.

```
SELECT * 
FROM groups g, items i, type1 t1, type2 t2, type3 t3, type4 t4, type5 t5, type6 t6
WHERE g.groupID = i.groupID
AND
// Now determine which type table has the related record
// e.g. if related item type1: 
// AND i.itemID = t1.itemID
AND g.groupID = 2
```

As part of the query, for each item in the group, I need to return that item including its related type record.

Sample data for the above query result would be:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| groupID | groupName | itemID | itemName    | applianceID | energyRating | ballID  | inflateTo | Size         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2       | Selling   | 11     | Kettle      | 20          | 5            | //empty | //empty   | //empty      | 
| 2       | Selling   | 12     | Soccer Ball | //empty     | //empty      | 34      | 40 psi    | Professional |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I build the query to include the right type information for each item in the group?

Comment: item can only be 1 type or multiple type?

Comment: Please edtit your question with sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.